# Find number of times multiple products were purchased grouped by Customer SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to run a query to find how many times a customer ordered product x and product y. The customer must have purchased product 10 in order to be shown. And if there is a way to add another column to flag true or false if the amount of products match. There is also a second table holding customer information.

```
CustomerID      ProductID
    1              10
    1              10
    1              11
    2              10
    2              9
    3              11
    3              9
```

Result: (Remember if customer did not order Product_10 he/she will not show in results.

```
 Customer    Product_10   Product_11
    John          2            1
    Mike          1            0
```

Comment: Your input data consists of two columns, both are numbers.  Your output consists of a column that has a name.  Where does the name come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a careful look at how the "Product_10" and "Product_11" columns are calculated; they're the crux of what you're trying to do. The `HAVING` at the end lops off any customers who don't have "Product_10" orders:

```
SELECT
  Customers.Customer,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Products.ProductID = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Product_10,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Products.ProductID = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Product_11
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Products ON Customers.ProductID = Products.ProductID
GROUP BY Customers.Customer
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Products.ProductID = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

The `Customers` table and columns are guesses because you didn't post the structure. Alter them as needed.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using a derived table for each product. The first derived table `t10` contains the # of product 10 purchased per customerId and this table is inner joined so that only customers with at least 1 purchase are shown, while the second table `t11` is left joined so even customers w/o any purchases are shown.

```
select c.customer, t10.p10_count Product_10, 
    coalesce(t11.p11_count,0) Product_11,
    (t10.p10_count = t11.p11_count) flag
from customer c
join (select CustomerID, count(*) p10_count
    from customer_products
    where ProductID = 10
    group by CustomerID) t10 
on t10.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
left join (select CustomerID, count(*) p11_count
    from customer_products
    where ProductID = 11
    group by CustomerID) t11 
on t11.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
```